# Save form data if Apply Settings button is clicked, else revert to old data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery to make a search filter menu. This form contains several form elements like checkbox and input box. When a user make some changes to the form and click on a `#apply-filters` button, the form will be hidden, and its data will be sent to the server backend for processing via `$.post()`.

If the user made changes to the form but closes it without clicking the `#apply-filters` button, the filter menu `div` will be hidden, and the next time the user reopens the filter menu, the initial settings will be shown, not the most recent settings that the user made but failed to click on `#apply-filters`.

**Problelm:** What is the best way to do this in jQuery?

**HTML**

```
<form id="filter-menu">
    <input type="checkbox" id="free" name="free" /><label for="free">Free</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="sale" name="sale" /><label for="sale">Sale</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="rooms_1" name="rooms[]" value=1/><label for="rooms_1">1 Room</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="rooms_2" name="rooms[]" value=2 /><label for="rooms_2">2 Rooms</label>

    <input type="text" id="price" val="100" />

    <button id="apply-filers">Apply Filters</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#apply-filters').click(function() {
    $('#filter-menu').serializeArray();  // Gives an empty array

    $.post('api/someplace', 
            { free: 1,
            sale: 1,
            rooms: [1, 2],
            price: 100
            }, function() {
                console.log('yay');
            });
});
```

---

### UPDATE

When I do

```
JSON.stringify($('filter-form').serializeArray())
```

I get

```
[{"name":"rooms[]","value":"1"},{"name":"rooms[]","value":"2"}]"
```

However I want to send it to server side via `$.post()` like

```
{rooms: [1,2]}
```

This way I will be able to do on the server side (PHP, after processing with the frameworks function)

```
$rooms = implode(',', $rooms_array)    // gives `1,2`
```

and the MySQL query can be like

```
SELECT .... WHERE rooms IN (1,2)
```

Is this possible? What would be a good way to send to the server side? Also, how would I use the output from `serializeArray()` to feed into `$.post()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `serializeArray` method returns empty array as your form elements have no `name` attributes.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="free" name='something' />
```

If you want to reset the form values you can use JavaScript `reset` method.

```
$('#close').click(function(){
    $('#something').hide()
    $("#filter-menu")[0].reset();
})
```

---

```
$('#apply-filters').click(function() {
     var room = $('#filter-menu input[name="rooms[]"]:checked').map(function(){
             return this.value
     }).get();  

    $.post('api/someplace', 
            { free: 1,
            sale: 1,
            rooms: room,
            price: 100
            }, function() {
                console.log('yay');
    });
});
```

Comment: I edited the code snippet with `name` and `value`. When I do `JSON.stringify($('filter-menu').serializeArray())` I get `[{"name":"rooms[]","value":"1"},{"name":"rooms[]","value":"2"}]"` However I want to send it to server side like `{rooms: [1,2]}` via `$.post()`, is this possible?

Comment: Updated the original post again with how I wish to treat the form data after passing them to the server.

Comment: @Nyxynyx Yes, it's possible using `map` method.

Comment: As for resetting the form data, I'll want to revert the settings when the `#apply-filter` button was last pressed, and remove any changes made since then. I tried '$('filter-menu')[0].reset()` as suggested and it successfully cleared the form which is not what I want. I guess the form data have to be saved somehow and retrieved

Comment: @Nyxynyx You are welcome, Can you clear the data in your post callback? What do you mean by last pressed?

Comment: Say a user checked `rooms_1` and `rooms_2` and clicks on the `#apply-filter` button. Now he decides to just search for 1 room, so he unchecks `rooms_2`, but did not click on the `#apply-filter` button. He closes the `filter-menu` div and the next time he opens it again, he will see both `rooms_1` and `rooms_2` checked. His last action on unchecking `rooms_2` will not be saved/applied because he did not click on `#apply-filter` button.

Comment: @Nyxynyx Why? This way you should store all the set values in your click handler, and when user opens the form set the values accordingly, you can use map method, but I don't think it's needed according to user-experience.

Comment: On second thought, I guess you are correct that its not necessary. Thank you undefined! :)